# Could someone please step me through the process of answering the Probability question?

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

Suppose that three unbiased dice are rolled. Find the probability that at least two of the three dice have a face value of five or more. Give your answer to two decimal places.

I understand there are 216 different outcomes from rolling 3 dice and i think there are 72 different ways that you can have at least 2 dice showing a 5 or 6.

I believe that i need to use the binomial coefficient but i cannot work out what my n or my k is for n choose k.

I have simulated all the outcomes in excel by just listing all the outcomes if die 1 was a 5 and die 2 was a 5 then die 3 can be any 1 to 6. I repeated this process for all the different outcomes of throwing the 3 dice and then deleted the duplicates and got 56. Therefore i think the final answer is 56/216 = 0.26 (2dp). The idea though is to use the binomial coefficient but i am unsure what my n and k numbers would be in this experiment.

Thanks

Comment: Hii, welcome to MSE. Users on this site like to answer those questions where the questioner put some effort by showing their work or adding their thoughts about the problem. As your post is lacking your attempt, there are possibilities that your question will attract some downvotes and may even be closed. To prevent that, please edit your question and provide context. Have a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/1010982) post to know How to ask a good question on this site and what's the purpose of this site.

Comment: Hi, the edit made it a lot better! Can you say a bit about how you got the number 72?

Comment: If your problem is just deciding what *n* and *k* are in this context, $n$ is the number of throws of a single die ($3$) and *k* is the number of "successes", $0,1,2,3$

Comment: Actually i just simulated all the outcomes in excel by just listing all the outcomes if die 1 was a 5 and die 2 was a 5 then die 3 can be any 1 to 6. I repeated this process for all the different outcomes of throwing the 3 dice and then deleted the duplicates and got 56. Therefore i think the final answer is 56/216 = 0.30 (2dp). The idea though is to use the binomial coefficient but i am unsure what my n and k numbers would be in this experiment.

Comment: wait 56/216 = 0.26 (2dp).. beside the point.. my point is how do i use the binomial coefficient to find the k = 56 possible ways? thanks.

Comment: Since you are new, I have tried to give a strong hint, but please note for future that whatever attempt you have made should be shown in the question itself, not in the comments.

Comment: I have put my comment of my working into my question. Please open my question back up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(0) =$ no dice has a value of $5$ or $6 = \binom30 (\frac13) ^0(\frac23) ^3$

$P(1) =$ one die has a value of $5$ or $6 = \binom31(\frac13)^1(\frac23)^2$

P(at least $2$ dice show a $5$ or $6$) $= 1 - [P(0) +P(1)]$

You should now be able to work it out.

**PS**

Now that you understand how the binomial coefficients come in, you could also work out the probability as $P(2)+P(3)$

Comment: Hi true blue anil, thank you for your answer. I think i understand that the 1/3 is the chance of rolling a 5 or a 6 and the 2/3 is the chance of not rolling a 5 or a 6 on any one dice. Can you please explain how/why the exponents change as you change the value of k? I think in your 3rd line of your answer you mean P(at least 1 die shows a value of 5 or 6) not 2?

Comment: Thank you true blue anil, you have put me on the correct path and i can now get the answer without having to simulate the experiment in excel. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi anil, i have worked out for myself why the exponents change -> it is distributing the number of dices (n) across the probabilities required for the event.

Comment: Glad to be of help ! :-)